# Simple DNS server in a docker container returns server unknown

Tags: linux, nginx, domain-name-system

its my first time posting here.
I am trying to configure a DNS server with nginx so two docker containers.
for some reason, when I do nslookup ns.main.com, it is returning server: unknown.

Here is my DNS file

```
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA ns.main.com. hostmaster.main.com. (
                    202      ; Serial
                    600      ; Refresh
                    3600     ; Retry
                    1209600  ; Expire
                    3600)    ; Negative Cache TTL

@       IN      NS      ns.main.com.
ns      IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

I am doing this locally so I am using the loopback address.
when I do nslookup ns.main.com, i get this message:

```
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  fd28:8d22:2169:0:9221:6ff:feb3:1438
```

named.config file look like this:

```
options {
  directory "var/bind";
  allow-transfer { "none"; };
  allow-query { any; };
  listen-on { any; };
};

zone "main.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/main.com";
};

zone "secondary.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zone/secondary.com";
};
```

What could be wrong here?

This is the tutorial I am following.

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GlCloo47p_E&list=PLOLrQ9Pn6cawvMA5JjhzoQrnKbYGYQqx1&index=3&ab_channel=VeryAcademy
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing this locally so I am using the loopback address. when I do nslookup ns.main.com, i get this message...

What command are you running specifically? If you simply run `nslookup ns.main.com`, nslookup will look in `/etc/resolv.conf` to find a nameserver, which probably isn't what you want.

You can provide `nslookup` with an explicit server by passing it a second command line argument:

```
nslookup <name_to_lookup> <server_to_query>
```

There is one typo in your `named.conf`; you have:

```
  directory "var/bind";
```

When you probably mean:

```
  directory "/var/bind";
```

You will also need to ensure that directory exists.

If I deploy your `named.conf` with the above change and place your zone records in `/etc/bind/zone/main.com`, then `nslookup` seems to work correctly:

```
# nslookup ns.main.com localhost
Server:         localhost
Address:        ::1#53

Name:   ns.main.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

---

I've made a complete Dockerfile and associated files available [here](https://github.com/larsks/sf-example-1121036-named) as a demonstration; if you build an image:

```
$ docker build -t named .
```

And then run it:

```
$ docker run --name named --rm -d named
```

You can verify that it works:

```
$ docker exec named nslookup ns.main.com localhost
Server:         localhost
Address:        ::1#53

Name:   ns.main.com
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you, and thank you for having a look, i really wanted to get this working